# Unable to find groovy-eclipse-batch artifact

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I am using below configuration in pom.xml. When i run "mvn install" on my local machine, it works. When ran from Jenkins, it throws error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project common: Fatal error compiling: Could not find groovy-eclipse-batch artifact. Must add this artifact as an explicit dependency the pom
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project common: Fatal error compiling
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven32Launcher.main(Maven32Launcher.java:132)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven32Main.launch(Maven32Main.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:136)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:71)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:120)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Fatal error compiling
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:796)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.CompilerException: Could not find groovy-eclipse-batch artifact. Must add this artifact as an explicit dependency the pom.
    at org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.compiler.GroovyEclipseCompiler.checkForGroovyEclipseBatch(GroovyEclipseCompiler.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.compiler.GroovyEclipseCompiler.performCompile(GroovyEclipseCompiler.java:87)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:785)
    ... 33 more
```

Parent pom.xml -->

```
<properties>
    <groovy.eclipse.batch.version>2.3.7-01</groovy.eclipse.batch.version>
    <groovy.eclipse.compiler.version>2.9.1-01</groovy.eclipse.compiler.version>
    <maven.compiler.version>3.1</maven.compiler.version>
</properties>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <!-- 2.8.0-01 and later require maven-compiler-plugin 3.1 or higher -->
    <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy.eclipse.compiler.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    <!-- for 2.8.0-01 and later you must have an explicit dependency on groovy-eclipse-batch -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy.eclipse.batch.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

I referred to this link https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/wiki/Groovy-Eclipse-Maven-plugin for configuring the above pom.xml entries.

Please note that i am using multi module pom configurations and this error comes on the sub module that it tries to compile first.

Comment: This should work, especially when Maven builds the project successfully on your computer.

Comment: See here for a working configuration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35718796/could-not-find-groovy-eclipse-batch-artifact