# Could not find groovy-eclipse-batch artifact

Tags: maven, groovy

I am trying to run `mvn clean compile` with java 8, previously I was working with java 7 that was working correctly.

Getting following error with java 8:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.
1:compile (default-compile) on project orion2-core: Fatal error compiling: Could
 not find groovy-eclipse-batch artifact. Must add this artifact as an explicit d
ependency the pom. -> [Help 1]`

Did following changes in Pom to run maven build wtih java 8:-

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <javaAgentClass>lombok.core.Agent</javaAgentClass>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    <version>0.12.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9.0-01-SNAPSHOT</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.4-01</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
 </plugin>
```

Comment: A reason why you using groovy compiler? Are you working with Groovy?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.0-01</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.6-02</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Not sure about lombok. What I noticed is that this is brittle. Not all versions of these JARs play well together (compiler 3.1 doesn't like groovy-eclipse-compiler 3.3, for example). If you get errors, try different versions.

Use the search form of Maven Central to find all possible versions: https://search.maven.org/search?q=a:groovy-eclipse-compiler

Answer (score 0):

put dependencies outside the plugin tag.

```
<plugin>
</plugin>
```

> `<dependencies> ... </dependencies>`

Comment: This is wrong. These are dependencies of the compiler plugin, not the project.